# How to generate a list of activable tasks in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm programming a task scheduler in Prolog. I have a set of predicates that define when a task can be considered activable, like this:

```
task(id01).
task(id02).
task(id03).
task(id04).

activable(X) :-
    task(X),
    inactive(X),
    conditions1(X).
activable(X) :-
    task(X),
    inactive(X)
    conditions2(X).
activable(X) :-
    task(X),
    inactive(X),
    conditions3(X).
```

I wonder how may I generate a list of all activable tasks, before activating any of them. I tried with something like this:

```
handle_activable([A|As]) :-
    activable(A),
    handle_activable(As).
handle_activable([]).

schedule :-
    handle_activable(As),
    activate_all(As).
```

But when I call `schedule/0`, I always get the first task checked, `task(id01)`, and the first `activable/1` clause goals constantly. I know it's silly but I can't find how to get a list of activable tasks. Even simpler, how to generate a list of tasks...?

Comment: Do you think you'd see a problem if `conditions1` and `conditions2` / `conditions3` were `true` for the same task?

Comment: Let's assume `conditions1`, `2` and `3` can't be true at the same time for the same task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prolog has a particular execution flow. Alternatives are considered on backtracking. Then you need to use some builtin that internally use backtracking, like [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.30%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29) does, or a *failure driven loop* like [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2), if you are interested in generating side effects for each solution you can find.

Bottom line:

```
schedule :-
    findall(A, activable(A), As),
    activate_all(As).
```

or

```
schedule :-
    forall(activable(A), activate(A)).
```

where activate/1 implements the side effect

Comment: Thanks @CapelliC `findall/3` was exactly what I needed. I wonder how did you learn all this Prolog knowledge you proved to have in several occasions. Thanks a lot for sharing it!!